# How to assign Enum to variable?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

The title says it all: how do I assign an Enum to a local variable like:

```
export enum MyEnum {
    TOP = "top",
    RIGHT = "right",
    BOTTOM = "bottom",
    LEFT = "left"
};

const myEnum: MyEnum = MyEnum; // <-Error: Type 'typeof MyEnum' is not assignable to type 'MyEnum'.
```

Link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20enum%20MyEnum%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TOP%20%3D%20%22top%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20RIGHT%20%3D%20%22right%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20BOTTOM%20%3D%20%22bottom%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20LEFT%20%3D%20%22left%22%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myEnum%3A%20MyEnum%20%3D%20MyEnum%3B).

In order someone wonders why I would do that:
I want to iterate over the Enum values in my AngularJs template:

```
// component controller
export class MyClass {
  public myEnum: MyEnum;

  constructor() {
    this.myEnum = MyEnum;
  }
}

// component template
<ul> 
  <li ng-repeat="enum in $ctrl.myEnum">{{ enum }}</li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

I know that I could assign every single value like:

```
constructor() {
  this.myEnum = {};
  this.myEnum.TOP = MyEnum.TOP;
  this.myEnum.RIGHT= MyEnum.RIGHT;
  this.myEnum.BOTTOM= MyEnum.BOTTOM;
  this.myEnum.LEFT= MyEnum.LEFT;
}
```

But this is not what I want. Not handy, very error prone.

Comment: You are trying to assign the type MyEnum to a variable as apposed to assigning an enum value like MyEnum.TOP.

Comment: Yes, that's kind of the problem. For sure I can assign every single value of the Enum by hand to my local variable, but this is not very handy and very error prone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `typeof MyEnum` to refer to the type of the entire enum namespace as opposed to the type of an enum member:

```
export class MyClass {
  public myEnum: typeof MyEnum;

  constructor() {
    this.myEnum = MyEnum;
  }
}
```

But it might be easier to use a property initializer so TypeScript will infer the type and you don't have to use a type annotation at all:

```
export class MyClass {
  public myEnum = MyEnum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first solutions work well, the second does not. myEnum keeps undefined.

Comment: It's strange that the second solution didn't work, since the emitted JavaScript code should be identical.  It worked for me in a simple test.  If you're interested in tracking this down, please add example code sufficient to reproduce the problem to the question.

Comment: hmm that's strange. I could make the second one work on fiddlesalad (I am not able to share that ... ). So I am going to find out, why it is undefined in my case.

Comment: Doh! typo.. I wrote `public myEnum: MyEnum;` instead of `public myEnum = MyEnum;`